# Three.Js positioning problem and coneGeometry error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to build a rocketship model by add different shapes to a large group and position them at specific axis.

When I try to use

```
rocketConeMesh.position.y = 15;
```

The shape does not move at all, I am trying to put the `rocketCone` (The nose of the rocket ship) on top of the `rocketBody` and then have them under the same group.

I get the followig error message

> `"THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. "`

for the `coneGeometry` object.

my code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            // create a render and set the size
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            window.addEventListener('resize', function()
            {
                var width = window.innerWidth;
                var height = window.innerHeight;
                renderer.setSize(width, height);
                camera.aspect = width / height;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            } );

          controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            // create the object group that contains all the sub-shapes
            var rocketGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
            scene.add(rocketGroup);

            //The object below is the top cone of the rocket
            var rocketCone = new THREE.ConeGeometry(6, 10, 6);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xcccccc, wireframe: true});
            var cone = new THREE.Mesh(rocketCone, material);
            rocketConeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketCone,new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial())

            scene.add(cone);
            //Specify the position of the rocket cone
            rocketConeMesh.position.y = 15;

            //Add the rocketCone to the lowpolyRocket group
            rocketGroup.add(rocketCone);

            /******************************************************************************************************************/

            //var rocketBody = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 5, 20, 32 );
            //var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xcccccc, wireframe:false});
            //var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBody, material);
            //scene.add(cylinder);

            // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
            camera.position.x = -30;
            camera.position.y = 20;
            camera.position.z = 30;
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            // game logic    
            var update = function ( )
            {
                //cone.rotation.x += 0.01;
                //cone.rotation.y += 0.005;
            };
            // draw scene    
            var render = function ( )
            {
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };



            // run game loop (update, render, repeat)
            var GameLoop = function ( )
            {
                requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);
                update( );
                render( );
            };
            GameLoop( );



        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> rocketGroup.add(rocketCone);

This code is not valid since it's not possible to add an instance of `ConeGeometry` to an `Object3D`. Try to change your code to the following:

```
rocketGroup.add(rocketConeMesh);
```

Now you add the mesh (which is derived from `THREE.Object3D`) to `rocketGroup`. It's now part of the scene graph and changing its transformation should work.

BTW: I don't understand why you create two meshes with your `rocketCone` geometry. I guess you can remove the `cone` variable.

Comment: are you referring to the Scene.add(cone)? After making that change, the errors go away but if I adjust the y axis for the position, it'd just trim the cone rather than moving it upwards

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? The mentioned part of your code is a bit confusing and I don't understand why you have implemented it this way. I mean why do you have two cone meshes?

Comment: I've not intended to do two meshes, so I have no reason. But I'm trying to add several different meshes to one group. so the rocketGroup would consist of the rocketCone, rocketBody, rocketTail etc.

Comment: In this case you can delete `cone` and just use `rocketConeMesh`.

Comment: using " var rocketConeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketCone,new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());" removes the cone from my scene. for some reason it doesn't recognise it. but it doesn't display any errors

Comment: If you share your code as a live example, I can have a look at it. Right now, it's really hard to provide more help since many things can be responsible for your problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to structure the code when displaying it on jsfiddle. it wont show it the same way

Comment: I tried to make a jfiddle, but it doesn't show my stuff https://jsfiddle.net/dnukj9mx/5/

Comment: Here is the update version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/equoy7mr/1/. The problem was that `MeshPhongMaterial` is only visible when you add lights to your scene. Instead `MeshBasicMaterial` is an unlit material and thus also visible without any lights.